# How can set directory path

Tags: java, path, directory

I want to set personal images in `drawable`.

```
package info.androidhive.imageslider.helper;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class AppConstant {

// Number of columns of Grid View
public static final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 3;

// Gridview image padding
public static final int GRID_PADDING = 8; // in dp

// SD card image directory
public static final String PHOTO_ALBUM = "NAT";
public static final String PHOTO_ALBUM =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/DCIM/"+"/100ANDRO/";

// supported file formats list 
public static final List<String> FILE_EXTN = Arrays.asList("jpg", "jpeg",
        "png");
}
```

Comment: fix your post formatting at first

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
String PHOTO_ALBUM =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/DCIM/"+"/100ANDRO/";
File f = new File(PHOTO_ALBUM );        
File file[] = f.listFiles();
for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
{
    String file_extension=file[i].getName().split(".");
    if(file_extension[file_extension.length-1].equalsIgnoreCase("jpg"))
   {
     // code here set image to imageview
      Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file[i]);
      //ImageView img;
      //img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
   }  
    else if(file_extension[file_extension.length-1].equalsIgnoreCase("png"))
   {
    // code here set image to imageview
   } 
  //.. so on
}
```

**Add Permission to Read External Storage**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

`public class PicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //use the default gallery background image
    int defaultItemBackground;

    //gallery context
    private Context galleryContext;

    //array to store bitmaps to display
    private Bitmap[] imageBitmaps;
    //placeholder bitmap for empty spaces in gallery
    Bitmap placeholder;

    //constructor
    public PicAdapter(Context c) {

        //instantiate context
        galleryContext = c;

        //create bitmap array

        String folderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/"+"/100ANDRO/";
        File filePath = new File(folderPath);
        File[] fileList = filePath.listFiles();
        imageBitmaps  = new Bitmap[fileList.length];
        for(int j = 0; j < fileList.length; j++) {
            imageBitmaps[j] =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileList[j].toString());
        }
        //System.out.println("==styleCode==" + styleCode + "=strExecutive="+ strExecutive);
        //decode the placeholder image
      //  placeholder = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/"+strExecutive+"/"+styleCode+"/");
        picView.setImageBitmap(placeholder);
       // placeholder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        //set placeholder as all thumbnail images in the gallery initially
        for(int i=0; i<imageBitmaps.length; i++)
            imageBitmaps[i]=placeholder;

        //get the styling attributes - use default Andorid system resources
        TypedArray styleAttrs = galleryContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.PicGallery);
        //get the background resource
        defaultItemBackground = styleAttrs.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.PicGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        //recycle attributes
        styleAttrs.recycle();
    }`

Comment: sir,Actually I want to add my personal pic from my computer data in this project. & also there "NAT" error on run time. help